# CSS Transform like open door

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to create an animation of opening and closing the door
But somewhere I made a mistake
Left top corner and left bottom corner look not like i want
maybe someone knows what the problem is
Here is my code

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flipbox{
  
  height: 420px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 18px solid grey;
  
}
.flipbox-active{
  height: 420px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #000;
  
  
}
.flipbox-active:hover{
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) translateX(-10%);
  transition: .45s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flipbox">
    <div class="flipbox-active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `transform-origin: left`

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flipbox{
  
  height: 420px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 18px solid grey;
  
}
.flipbox-active{
  height: 420px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform .45s;
  
  
}
.flipbox-active:hover{
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flipbox">
    <div class="flipbox-active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost good, simply adjust the origin instead of adding a translation:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.flipbox{
  
  height: 420px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 18px solid grey;
  
}
.flipbox-active{
  height: 420px;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #000;
  transform-origin:left;
  
  
}
.flipbox-active:hover{
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg);
  transition: .45s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flipbox">
    <div class="flipbox-active">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```